# Must getter in Java return always only field value according to naming convention?

Tags: java

The `getXXX` is used as getter for `XXX`. For example

```
class Foo {

  private String XXX;

  public String getXXX() {
      return XXX;
  }
}
```

So, its clear and there is no question about it. Now let's consider the following situation:

```
class Foo {

   public String getXXX() {
     String XXX;
     //some calculations, resolvings etc
     return XXX;
   }
}
```

Can I name in such case my method as `getXXX` according to naming convention? Or by other words, does `getXXX` suppose that there is `XXX` field in class and we want return this field value according to naming convention?

Comment: Somethin IDE would say yes, in Intellij, if you name  method getXXX and there is no XXX field, it'll give you a warning

Comment: Create a method updateXXX() which will "do some calculations, resolvings etc". and update XXX value and then call a getXXX method to get the updated value.

Comment: Part of the point of getters is that you can put code in there that outside code doesn't have to worry about. Whatever calls `getXXX()` might imagine that your class has a field called `XXX` that is simply returned, but whether it actually does that or something else is an implementation detail.

Comment: Just don't forget to add Javadoc documentation to your method. Then it will be clear for everyone what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Getters are not covered by general java naming convention:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

2) Getters are part of javabeans naming convention, where you define getXxx/isXxx method to get value of property xxx. Meanwhile you are not bound to keep this getter in sync with member variable - member variable is private (package private) and that's intended. You can even get rid of member variable if you have to - bean property exists when there are accessor methods.

That is, knowing what you are doing, you can use any calculations in getter and setter.

3) Even though you can use calculations, it's good practice to keep getters fast. No one expects your getter to calculate something for hour.

If you have to calculate something big first time, make some cache and don't run calculations every time. It's also good idea to make calculations in special init()/prepare() method.

Also it's good idea to add javadoc comment to your getter.

4) The problem arises if you expose member variable to class users. For example, if you bind properties to member variables in JAXB, getter with special functionality can be missed.

For such cases POJO without getters might be easier to handle than complex class with customized behaviour. But there is nothing wrong with careful set up of accessors binding, it just takes few more buttons and a bit of extra thinking.

Comment: Agree with almost everything except for `it's a good idea to add javadoc comment to your getter`. Comments are usually a bad idea as code evolves and comments in 99% cases stay the same, method name should be self-explained and I guess getter it the simplest case when method name exactly says what the method does.

Comment: Note that the official java naming convention that you quoted is really old (1999 by Sun), it gives some useful information but it is absolutely not enough to cover the actual standards.

Answer (score 3):

As I write a method that returns something and that is not a dumb getter I often think before prefixing it by `get` to avoid giving the feeling to the class clients that the method is a dumb getter.
For example supposing that it makes a relative expensive computation, a name such as `getFoo()` may be misleading.

Generally if I find a better prefix than `get` I use it.  For example sometimes `find()` or `compute()` can make more sense.
But as other prefixes don't match,  I don't try to be too clever and I keep `get`.
Additionally, to be clearer you should use javadoc to specify the contract and the intention of the method if it matters and can make the API more friendly for the clients of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you always wanted to do some operation on the returned value, then you can use `getXXX`, otherwise, go for a separate name as you may want to read the original value somewhere along the line.